# I will try to sent many data to mysql with python but not work

Tags: python, mysql

my program are sent data to mysql with python language count data are 73 (I am check count of data and %s is correct 73)
I show part sent data to Mysql because Except this part works normally.

```
data = (
    devIds, inverter_state, pv1_v, pv2_v, pv3_v, pv4_v, pv5_v, pv6_v, pv7_v, pv8_v, pv9_v, pv10_v,
    pv11_v, pv12_v, pv13_v, pv14_v, pv15_v, pv16_v, pv17_v, pv18_v, pv19_v, pv20_v,
    pv21_v, pv22_v, pv23_v, pv24_v, pv25_v, pv26_v, pv27_v, pv28_v, pv1_i, pv2_i, pv3_i, pv4_i, pv5_i,
    pv6_i, pv7_i, pv8_i, pv9_i, pv10_i, pv11_i, pv12_i, pv13_i, pv14_i, pv15_i, pv16_i, pv17_i,
    pv18_i, pv19_i, pv20_i, pv21_i, pv22_i, pv23_i, pv24_i, pv25_i, pv26_i, pv27_i, pv28_i,
    Total_yield, Inverter_startup_time, Inverter_shutdown_time, mppt_total_energy, MPPT_1,
    MPPT_2, MPPT_3, MPPT_4, MPPT_5, MPPT_6, MPPT_7, MPPT_8, MPPT_9, MPPT_10, run_state
    )
cleaned_data.append(data)

query = "INSERT INTO device_data_string (devIds, inverter_state, pv1_v, pv2_v, pv3_v, pv4_v, pv5_v, pv6_v, pv7_v, pv8_v, pv9_v, pv10_v, pv11_v, pv12_v, pv13_v, pv14_v, pv15_v, pv16_v, pv17_v, pv18_v, pv19_v, pv20_v, pv21_v, pv22_v, pv23_v, pv24_v, pv25_v, pv26_v, pv27_v, pv28_v, pv1_i, pv2_i, pv3_i, pv4_i, pv5_i, pv6_i, pv7_i, pv8_i, pv9_i, pv10_i, pv11_i, pv12_i, pv13_i, pv14_i, pv15_i, pv16_i, pv17_i, pv18_i, pv19_i, pv20_i, pv21_i, pv22_i, pv23_i, pv24_i, pv25_i, pv26_i, pv27_i, pv28_i, Total_yield, Inverter_startup_time, Inverter_shutdown_time, mppt_total_energy, MPPT_1, MPPT_2, MPPT_3, MPPT_4, MPPT_5, MPPT_6, MPPT_7, MPPT_8, MPPT_9, MPPT_10, run_state) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

mycursor.executemany(query, cleaned_data)
mydb.commit()
```

error this
`mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Not enough parameters for the SQL statement`

I am check count of "%s" in VALUE by

```
query = "INSERT INTO device_data_string (devIds, inverter_state, pv1_v, pv2_v, pv3_v, pv4_v, pv5_v, pv6_v, pv7_v, pv8_v, pv9_v, pv10_v, pv11_v, pv12_v, pv13_v, pv14_v, pv15_v, pv16_v, pv17_v, pv18_v, pv19_v, pv20_v, pv21_v, pv22_v, pv23_v, pv24_v, pv25_v, pv26_v, pv27_v, pv28_v, pv1_i, pv2_i, pv3_i, pv4_i, pv5_i, pv6_i, pv7_i, pv8_i, pv9_i, pv10_i, pv11_i, pv12_i, pv13_i, pv14_i, pv15_i, pv16_i, pv17_i, pv18_i, pv19_i, pv20_i, pv21_i, pv22_i, pv23_i, pv24_i, pv25_i, pv26_i, pv27_i, pv28_i, Total_yield, Inverter_startup_time, Inverter_shutdown_time, mppt_total_energy, MPPT_1, MPPT_2, MPPT_3, MPPT_4, MPPT_5, MPPT_6, MPPT_7, MPPT_8, MPPT_9, MPPT_10, run_state) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
count = query.count("%s")
print(count)
```

result is
`73`
but I use chatGPT to count number are not 73
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUipT.png)

Comment: You're appending to `cleaned_data`. Maybe one of the other elements is the wrong length.

Comment: If you do `print(list(map(len, cleaned_data)))` are they all `73`?

Comment: So don´t use ChatGpt to count number of placeholders